# R regex match beginning and middle of a string

Tags: r, regex, string, matching

I have a vector of strings:

```
A <- c("Hello world", "Green 44", "Hot Beer", "Bip 6t")
```

I want to add an asterisk (*) at the beginning and at the end of every first word like this:

```
"*Hello* world", "*Green* 44", "*Hot* Beer", "*Bip* 6t"
```

Make sense to use `str_replace()` from `stringr`.
However, I am struggling with regex to match the first word of each string.

The best achievement ended up with:

```
str_replace(A, "^([A-Z])", "*\\1*"))
```

```
"*H*ello world", "*G*reen 44", "*H*ot Beer", "*B*ip 6t"
```

I might expect to be a straightforward task, but I am not getting along with regex.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there

```r
str_replace(A, "(^.*) ", "*\\1* ")
#> [1] "*Hello* world" "*Green* 44"    "*Hot* Beer"    "*Bip* 6t"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```r
sub("([[:alpha:]]+)", "*\\1*", A)
## => [1] "*Hello* world" "*Green* 44"    "*Hot* Beer"    "*Bip* 6t"
```

The `stringr` equivalent is

```r
library(stringr)
stringr::str_replace(A, "([[:alpha:]]+)", "*\\1*")
stringr::str_replace(A, "(\\p{L}+)", "*\\1*")
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/PDlcVV). See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/c4Xxsm/1).

The `([[:alpha:]]+)` regex matches and captures one or more letters into Group 1 and `*\1*` replacement replaces the match with `*` + Group 1 value  + `*`.

Note that `sub` finds and replaces the first match only, so only the first word is affected in each character vector.

**Notes**

- If you plan to wrap the word *exactly* at the start of a string (not just the "first word"), add `^` at the start of the pattern (e.g. `sub("^([[:alpha:]]+)", "*\\1*", A)`)
- If the word is a chunk of non-whitespace chars, use `\S+` instead of `[[:alpha:]]+` or `\p{L}+`  (e.g. `sub("^(\\S+)", "*\\1*", A)`)
- If the word is any chunk of letters or digits or underscores, you can use `\w+`, i.e. `sub("^(\\w+)", "*\\1*", A)`
- If the word is any chunk of letters or digits but not underscores, you can use `[[:alnum:]]+`, i.e. `sub("^([[:alnum:]]+)", "*\\1*", A)`